# Compiling GLIBC-2.13 on Ubuntu 10.10 x86_64

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compilation, glibc

When trying to compile glibc on ubuntu 10.10, x86_64, i get the error:

```
../misc/syslog.c: In function ‘__vsyslog_chk’:
../misc/syslog.c:123: sorry, unimplemented: inlining failed in call to ‘syslog’: function body not available
../misc/syslog.c:155: sorry, unimplemented: called from here
make[2]: *** [/home/daniel/src/b.c/misc/syslog.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to rebuild something on Ubuntu that Debian already, you are almost always best of by starting with the original source package on Debian.

In this particular case you can start with [this version from the Debian experimental branch](http://packages.debian.org/experimental/libc6).  By using the source package, you ensure you have required build-dependencies and should minimize surprises.

Also, building in a chroot environment is a good way to do this and made easy by packages such as `pbuilder` and `sbuild`.

Edit: There are [build logs](https://buildd.debian.org/status/package.php?p=eglibc&suite=experimental) but they don't contain one for amd64, presumably because the maintainers built on that locally.  But you can look at i386, say, and see that it passed the error you had.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, but it sadly doesn't fix this

Answer (score 2):

Try this [wiki](http://plash.beasts.org/wiki/GlibcBuildIssues#head-b9149fbab065967691cf1bade23d84325c05e9b0) about glibc build issues.

I just ran into the same issue but with 32-bit.  When running the configure script, adding CFLAGS='-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -O2' to the command line seems to work.  You may need to add -mtune=i686 and -march=i686 in there too.  But maybe not for 64 bit.  The i686 seems to be another bug.